# How can i return an object that is tied to another object by a foreignkey?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model `Order`,

```
class Order(SmartModel):
    SUBMITTED = 1
    PROCESSED = 2 
    DELIVERED = 3 
    PICKED_UP = 4
    CANCELLED = 5
    ORDER_STATUSES = ((SUBMITTED,'Submitted'),(PROCESSED,'Processed'),(DELIVERED,'Delivered'),(PICKED_UP,'picked_up'),(CANCELLED,'Cancelled'),
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUSES, default=SUBMITTED)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,null=True,blank=True,default = None,help_text="The restaurant the customer order from")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,help_text="Needed as alternative")
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(max_length=20,default='+25078######',help_text="Needed to communicate and confirm payment from mobile money")
```

i create and save this object as follows,

```
def create_order(request,self):
    orders = Order()
    checkout_form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,instance=orders)
    orders = checkout_form.save(commit=False)
    anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
    orders.created_by = anon_user
    orders.modified_by = anon_user
    orders.status = Order.SUBMITTED
    orders.save()
        ......
```

my admin looks like so,

```
class OrderCRUDL(SmartCRUDL):
    model = Order
    permissions = True
    actions = ('list','read','create','delete','update')

    class List(SmartListView):
        fields = ('date','status','billing_name','mobile','email','billing_address','billing_city','restaurant','restaurant.services')
        search_fields = ('date',)
```

i want in the admin for a `restaurant` to view a list of only `orders` created from its menu on the web app. As of now, a restaurant can view a list of all orders made on the app.

How can i achieve this, suggestion of readings is also welcome.

here is the code am using and getting error `TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()`

```
def queryset(self,request):
    queryset = self.Order.objects.get_queryset()
    current_restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id=request.user)
    return queryset.filter(restaurant = current_restaurant)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using queryset filter in your admin class:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = self.model._default_manager.get_query_set()
    current_restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id = request.user) #You need to get current restaurant instance
    return qs.filter(restaurant = current_restaurant)
```

You need to get `current_restaurant` object by using current restaurant's login data. More information can be found in **Listing 14** in [documentation by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-django-admin/index.html).

Comment: m getting this error `object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()`

Comment: You have just copied and pasted the code I have given. You need to modify the code for your needs. Where did you use this code? How will you get the `current_restaurant` object?

Comment: i did modify it,just kept the same variables,i get the current_user by importing it and its also tied to `Order` as foreignkey.

Comment: What is the exception location? Also try to print `current_restaurant`.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to achieve results by doing something like this

```
def derive_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(OrderCRUDL.List, self).derive_queryset()
    #if super-user,show all comments
    if self.request.user.is_superuser:
       return queryset
    return queryset.filter(restaurant=self.request.user)
```